# Ryzen 5 2600x Rev. A versus Rev. F: What is difference in revs?

Tags: computer-hardware, computer

My son built a computer a few months ago with Gigabyte m/b and Ryzen 5 2600x. He bought the parts at a local Computer Super-Store and built it.

I liked it so much I bought the parts at the same local Computer Super-Store and built one for myself. Had some trouble with bad h/w but Super-Store allowed returns and now my computer runs great.

When we were attempting to determine why my computer might be having trouble we noticed only one difference: his Ryzen 5 2600x was marked Rev. F and mine was marked as Rev. A.

When I returned the m/b and CPU I thought maybe I'd get a Rev. F also but again it just so happened that it was a Rev. A and everything does work fine.

Now I'm very curious as to what the differences might be in those two Revs.

Do you know what the differences are? Do you know where I might find the differences listed?

Yes, I Googled (actually duckduckgo) but didn't find anything even mentioning the Revs.

Even on the official site on the specific CPU details I don't see anything: https://www.amd.com/en/support/cpu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-5-desktop-processors/amd-ryzen-5-2600x

Comment: Probably better on Hardware Recommendations Stack

Comment: I posted it there and they deleted it without me even knowing.  I almost lost the entire text of the post and I couldn't even tell what had happened.  The only way I got the text back was to go to the original computer where I posted the question and got it from the cache.  Thanks